# Speech Recognition. Module installed but won't work

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

Trying to get the speech recognition module to work. I have it working on my Windows 10 laptop, my Raspberry pi3 but I can't seem to get it to work on Ubuntu! The module has been install but neither PyCharm or Thonny can find it.

I've searched through stack overflow for a solution and haven't been successful. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module. I've tried various versions of installing the module such as using the setuup.py file or pip, tried moving the folders/files where they should be etc.. 
(Also tried telling the Computer he's a good boy but that didn't work either...)

I can use this line of code

```
python3 -m speech_recognition
```

With my mic plugged into the tower and it works, but when using a line in PyCharm or Thonny such as

```
import speech_recognition
print(speech_recognition.__version__)
```

I end up with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elitree/SPRECOG/FU.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

python version is 3.6
pip3 version is 19.1.1
Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
I can provide other system details if needed
I'm just not sure what to do now

Comment: Does your code work if you put it into a file and execute it with `python3 this_file.py`?

Comment: So when I run the code - that prints the Speech Recognition version - in the terminal it does indeed give me the version of Speech Recognition that I have installed.

Comment: This means that PyCharm is using the wrong Python interpreter. Run `which python3` to get the absolute path to the interpreter executable and configure the IDE to use it.

Comment: elitree@WELTO:~/Desktop$ python3 FU.py
3.8.1
The python file is just named that because I got annoyed

Comment: Thanks, I just re-adjusted the IDE for python3 which was displayed with "which python3" instead of python3.6 that it had as default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ForceBru explained to me - My IDE was using the wrong python interpreter.

Which is first identified by running the Python script in the terminal with `python3 this_file.py`

After this the problem could be fixed by identifying the correct interpreter using the command `which python3` in the terminal and then configuring the IDE to use that interpreter.